# Configurar e-mail de envio hospedagem redeHost

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Tenho um site no hospedado no redeHost, ao configurá-lo no PHP Mailer, não funcionou, entrei em contato com o suporte do redeHost, me disseram que o PHP Mailer é bloqueado no servidores deles, que deviria usar a função mail().

Consegui configurar e enviar somente texto, entretanto quando coloco arquivo anexado, não envia porque precisa de autenticação.

Alguém já configuro o email nessa hospegem? ou tem um exemplo da função mail() que seja autenticada, e permita anexo?

Comment: Olá Eduardo, sei que já tem um tempo este post, gostaria de saber como vc resolveu. Realmente a RedeHost não permite suporte ao uso do PHPMailer? Teria como mostrar o seu código com a função mail()? Felicidades.

Answer (score 2):

Fiquei com a "pulga atras da orelha" com a posição do suporte da redeHost, e tentei falar com outro atendente!

Pra minha surpresa, a solução foi totalmente diferente, pois como suspeitava, o outro técnico tinha falado groselha.

Solução: 
trocar o SMTP de mail.dominio.com.br 
para
**smtpexc01.redehost.com.br**

Comment: Infelizmente aqui temos que passar por este tipo de situação, atendentes ruins, mas a culpa é da empresa, não preparar e/ou filtra seus funcionários de maneira adequada.

Comment: Eduardo, vc poderia postar como ficou sua configuração, pois tenho o mesmo problema com a redehost.

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente, quando vc cria uma conta em uma hospedagem, é criado uma conta de email que será usada para fazer a conexão SMTP. Se vc não tiver essa conta, ou não sabe qual conta é essa, recomendo vc entrar em contato com a hospedagem. 
Ou se vc tiver acesso ao o painel administrativo, como por exemplo CPanel, vc mesmo pode criar/ver que conta é essa. Alguns host usam as portas 587, 25, ou 2525 para SMTP, vc dever ver com sua hospedagem qual seria.

Uma das coisas que pode dar errado, não sei se é o seu caso, mas é a questão do host SMTP, geralmente é um diferente do seu domínios, muitas veses é mail.seudomínio.com. Verifique com a empresa isso tbm.
Outra coisa, para usar a função mail, vc tem que realizar algumas configurações, como pro exemplo. 
php_flag authmail.debug: Habilita mensagens de erro no sistema.
php_value authmail.port: Define a porta que será utilizada para envio ( 587 ).
php_value authmail.address: Endereço de email que será utilizado.
php_value authmail.account: Usuário de acesso à conta de email.
php_value authmail.smtp: Servidor de envio de emails.
php_value authmail.password: Senha de acesso à conta de email.

Todas essas informações ficam em um arquivo .htaccess na pasta root.

Dá uma lida nesses links, pode te ajudar.

http://www.hostnet.com.br/wiki/index.php/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_mail()_do_PHP
http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/1031/php__enviando_e-mail_autenticado

valew.

Comment: A porta que o suporte da redeRost me sugeriu foi 587 mesmo.
Dei uma estudada no código, porem não consegui associal com munha necessidade de anexar arquivo... Por favor me ajude, sou novo em desenvolvimento web

Comment: Isso mesmo, kk esqueci de dizer tbm sobre vc dar um ping no host de email pra ver se retornava alguma coisa. Neste casa, me parece que eles tem um servidor de email específico.